# Document.referrer empty when navigating from external url?

Tags: http, dom

I have the following code:

```
var previousPageUrl= document.referrer;
alert(previousPageUrl);
```

This will not work if the previous page url is of any external site, i.e., not of my application.

For example:

If I am in Page 1 and went to Page 2 of my application then I will get page 1 url in referrer in Page 2 load but when I go to external site say www.google.com then again when I come back to page 1 the I will not get www.google.com as referrer url.

Can Somebody tell to resove this issue.

Answer (score 61):

Generally, Referer URLs *are* passed between unrelated sites when navigation occurs due to a link click or JavaScript-based navigation. Referer URLs are NOT sent if the user uses the browser's chrome (e.g. address bar, back/forward buttons/etc) to navigate.

For security/privacy reasons, the Referer URL is stripped out when navigating from a HTTPS site to a HTTP site (e.g. from https://google.com to http://example.com). It can also be deliberately stripped out via a variety of JavaScript and HTML tricks. There is no way to disable this behavior to get the Referer URL if it has been stripped.

Comment: Then in that case when I enter into my application from an external site by pressing browser's back button, then how will I sendthe user to home page without knowing if I am coming from external site.

Comment: Pressing the Back button will never send a Referer, as the site you're coming from didn't "refer" the user in any way.

Comment: Then how document.referrer gets the previous page url when we press browser back button within the application?

Comment: It doesn't, when the back button is pressed.