# javascript variable turned out empty

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

The following code (as a bookmarklet in chrome) does not work like I thought-----I could see alert popup but the content is empty.

```js
javascript:window.location.href='http://new.cloudfile.co/transfer';var tmp=document.referrer;alert(tmp);
```

In fact "alert()" is for debug, I want to directly assign this referrer url to an inputbox, instead of using "document.execCommand('paste')", which turned out to be failure. 
Anyway, why alert() got empty value here?
Please help, Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading the page this code is on?  Why do you expect [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) to have a value?  P.S. Why do you have `javascript:` there?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455450/document-referrer-empty-when-navigating-from-external-url

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's a bookmarklet. That's why `javascript:` is there

Comment: Perhaps you want `document.location` instead of `document.referrer` since the referring page is actually the current page (before the redirection).

Comment: @WesFoster Yes,sir, I do want to get url before the redirection.

Comment: You cannot execute code on the page you're redirecting to. You can only execute code on the current page open when executing the JS.