# Detects Redirect and open a modal (Popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns, redirect

I have a scenario trying to redirect DNS to another URL and i.e http://oldexample.com to another page of new website https://example.com.com/newpage

I am trying to make a script that detects traffic to https://example.com/newpage from http://oldexample.com and if it's detects that trigger to open modal/popup/alert message will saying some information on this page (https://example.com/newpage).

I have tried following solution but it does not work? Is it right way to implement it?

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var isExternal = document.referrer;
    console.log(isExternal);
    if (isExternal === "https://oldexample.com") {
     // Do something
    alert('Referred from expected page. Probably.');
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you put `console.log(isExternal)`

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon I am getting empty value. Nothing shows up.

Comment: Try looking at answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455450 and google: "document.referrer empty"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Document.referrer empty when navigating from external url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455450/document-referrer-empty-when-navigating-from-external-url)