# How to get forwarded domain to display in webpage using window.location?

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I am forwarding a handful of domain names to one domain. How do I display the forwarded domain name on the page?

I have tried using window.location.hostname and .host - however, the forwarded domain name does not display. Only the domain name the site was forwarded to. For example:

domain1.com is being forwarded to landingpage.com

domain1.com is what appears now on the browser's URL. However, the site is landingpage.com -  I assume window.location.hostname would fetch the information of domain1.com - however, when I display it in html, i only see landingpage.com

Any help would be appreciated.

document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = window.location.hostname;

Answer (score 0):

Domain Forwarding works by hosting a simple webpage containing an `iframe` that points to the page you want to show.

You can't read its location from the hosted page because [it requires the host to inject JS to make it possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue).

You **might** be able to read the [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) but that is [unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455450/document-referrer-empty-when-navigating-from-external-url).

---

In short, for this and a variety of other reasons, Domain Forwarding is **awful**. Get real domain hosting associated with your HTTP hosting instead.