# How can i get the previous page domain without using document.referrer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use document.referrer to get info of the previous page, sometimes it returns null, I wonder is any other method to get the domain of the previous page?

This is for front-end, ReactJs

Comment: Nope. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455529/3412322

Comment: all right, thanks! pass the referrer along seems the only way

Answer (score -1):

You may try either of this:

`window.history.back();`

`window.history.go(-1);`

In the second example, `go(-1)` reads as "Go 1 step back in history". You could use `go(-2)` to go back 2 steps and so on

Comment: But I need to grab the info of the previous page, not just navigate back

Comment: what kind of info do you need?

Comment: if you need  the actual referring URL, there's no 100% foolproof way to do it. There will be no referer if the URL to your site was typed in the browser's address bar, it may or may not be passed along under HTTPS, it won't work if the user has JS disabled, etc, so you shouldn't rely on having that info all the time

Comment: some info can tell whether the previous page is an external site or not