# Detect from where (which website) the http request came from

Tags: javascript

I want to build my own analytic and I need to know from where the requests are coming from with only javaScrpt, I can't believe that the browser is not holding somewhere in window object a variable about from where the request came from. It looks like there is no information in the net or I am not asking the right question.

I hope somebody met this problem before and has a solution :) Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer)

### Syntax

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

#### Value

The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark). Because this property returns only a string, it doesn't give you document object model (DOM) access to the referring page.

Inside an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the `Document.referrer` will initially be set to the same value as the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href) of the parent window's [`Window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: Thank you Pedro, It worked as I needed :) I just want to add for future dudes with the same problem... So when I tried "document.referrer" from One of my website to the one in development I got again an empty string. I found that If the request is from https to http (which was my case) we have the same empty result. I built the site and hosted to an https domain and everithing worked just fine. Thanks again ! The source of my knowege about https to http document.refferer empty string  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455450/document-referrer-empty-when-navigating-from-external-url)